# Passing params to function and casting

Tags: c

I am new to C language and I have some misunderstanding in the following exercise:

```
void printAllStrings(const char** arr[])
{
    while(*arr!=NULL)
    {
        char** ptr=(char**)*arr;
        while(*ptr!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n",*ptr);
            ptr++;
        }
        arr++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* arrP1[]={"father","mother",NULL};
    char* arrP2[]={"sister","brother","grandfather",NULL};
    char* arrP3[]={"grandmother",NULL};
    char* arrP4[]={"uncle","aunt",NULL};
    char** arrPP[]={arrP1,arrP2,arrP3,arrP4,NULL};

    printf("Before sort :\n");
    printAllStrings(arrPP);
    sort(arrPP);

    printf("\nAfter sort :\n");
    printAllStrings(arrPP);
    printf("\nMaximum length string : %s \n",maxLengthString(arrPP));

    return 0;
}
```

The code above prints all strings.

My questions is:

1. In `printAllStrings` function the the passed parameter(`char** arr[]`) array of strings, could we pass pointer on pointer - `char** arr`.
2. What the meaning of  this row `char** ptr=(char**)*arr`; I undersatnd that this casting of pointers to char type.
   But why the pointer have to be casted is already points to char type?

Comment: Btw `const char** arr[]` --> `char** arr[]` in the `printAllStrings()` definition.

Comment: Changing each declaration to `const`, e.g. `const char *arrP1[] = ...` will correct. Likewise, changing `const char **ptr = *arr;` will eliminate the cast. (of course changing to `const` will pose problems for `sort()`)

Comment: Can you please clarify question 1 I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to say there.

Comment: In question 1 your two code samples are the same

Comment: It looks like your issue is to declare a proper *array of constant pointers to char* along with an array of those arrays to pass to `sort`, making sure the *pointers to char* are `const` qualified -- rather than then arrays containing them.

Comment: The root of all problems here is that whoever wrote the code didn't understand the meaning of `const char** arr[]` or rather how to write const correctness for `char**` types. Which is, as it turns out, not an easy topic to grasp at all.

Comment: If they had used the following in main instead `char **PP = *(char**[]){arrP1, arrP2, arrP3, arrP4, NULL};` it would have saved lots of head ache. Then the functions could have type `const char**` and one wouldn't need to worry about array decay and array pointers and how const apply to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. In printAllStrings function the the passed parameter`(char** arr[])` array of strings, could we pass pointer on pointer - `char** arr[]`.

In your examples above, you have `char** arr[]` and `char** arr[]` (the two are the same) so your *"could we pass?"* question is unclear. If you are asking if you could change the parameter to `(char ***arr)`, then yes, you could because the first level of indirection (e.g. `[ ]`) is converted to a pointer.

> 2. What the meaning of this row `char** ptr=(char**)*arr`; I undersatnd that this casting of pointers to char type. But why the pointer have
>      to be casted is already points to char type?

The reason is your parameter is `const char** arr[]` and then you declare `char** ptr` which *discards the `const` qualifier* on `arr`. `const char **` and `char **` are not the same. So when you attempt to initialize `ptr` with the dereferenced `arr`, e.g. (`char** ptr=arr;`) the compiler complains about the discard of the `const` qualifier.

Rather than fixing the problem correctly, e.g.

```
const char **ptr = *arr;
```

you "fudge" the initialization to force the discard of the `const` qualifier -- resulting in `ptr` not retaining the `const` type which can prevent the compiler from warning when you attempt to use `ptr` in a non-constant way (really bad things happen when you just cast away `const` qualifiers)

I may be wrong -- but it looks like the point of the assignment is to have you preserve the `const` nature of the *string literals* you use to initialize your array of pointers. So rather than declaring the arrays as:

```
char* arrP1[]={"father","mother",NULL};
```

You should declare them as arrays of `const` pointers to char, e.g.

```
const char *arrP1[]={"father","mother",NULL};
```

Your parameter for `printAllStrings` then makes sense, and the compiler with warn if you try and do something you are not allowed to do like changing the string literals, e.g. if you try:

```
arrP1[0][0] = 'l';
```

(the compiler will throw `error: assignment of read-only location ‘*arrP1[0]`)

If you carry the types consistently through your code, you will not have to "fudge" with any casts anywhere, and the compiler can help protect you from yourself. For example, a simple rework of your types to make sure your string literals are `const` qualified (while still allowing you to sort your arrays) could be done with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printAllStrings (const char **arr[])
{
    while (*arr != NULL) {
        const char **ptr = *arr;
        while (*ptr != NULL) {
            printf ("%s\n", *ptr);
            ptr++;
        }
        arr++;
    }
}

const char *maxLengthString (const char **arr[])
{
    size_t max = 0;
    const char *longest = NULL;

    while (*arr != NULL) {
        const char **ptr = *arr;
        while (*ptr != NULL) {
            size_t len = strlen (*ptr);
            if (len > max) {
                max = len;
                longest = *ptr;
            }
            ptr++;
        }
        arr++;
    }
    return longest;
}

int main (void) {

    const char *arrP1[] = {"father", "mother", NULL};
    const char *arrP2[] = {"sister", "brother", "grandfather", NULL};
    const char *arrP3[] = {"grandmother", NULL};
    const char *arrP4[] = {"uncle", "aunt", NULL};
    const char **arrPP[] = {arrP1, arrP2, arrP3, arrP4, NULL};

    printf ("Before sort :\n");
    printAllStrings (arrPP);

    // sort (arrPP);  /* you didn't post sort, so the following swaps */
    const char **tmp = arrPP[0];    /* simple swap example */
    arrPP[0] = arrPP[1];
    arrPP[1] = tmp;

    printf ("\nAfter sort :\n");
    printAllStrings (arrPP);

    printf ("\nMaximum length string : %s \n", maxLengthString (arrPP));

    return 0;
}
```

(You didn't post `sort()`, so above the elements a simply swapped to show your `arrPP` retains the ability to be sorted, and a quick implementation of the `maxLengthString ()` was added to make your last statement work -- but note, it just finds the first of any longest strings if more than one are the same length)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_ptp_const_char
Before sort :
father
mother
sister
brother
grandfather
grandmother
uncle
aunt

After sort :
sister
brother
grandfather
father
mother
grandmother
uncle
aunt

Maximum length string : grandfather
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but based on your code and questions, it seemed the most logical choice.

Comment: Thanks for post.In my first question I wanted to ask if I can send as parameter char **arr

Comment: No. You have 1 too many levels of indirection. (1) `"father"` is `char *`, (2) then you have an array of pointers to char `"father", "mother", NULL`, that is `char *[]` (or just `char **` when converted to a pointer), (3) then you have an array of those in `arrPP` which is `char **[]` (or `char ***` when converted to a pointer)  The minimum you can pass and still be passing the entire data is `char **[]` (or equivalently `char ***`)

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer the 2nd question as I can not understand the 1st the way it is now.

```
char** ptr=(char**)*arr;
// this is the same but maybe confusing because arr is a pointer now and it gets iterated in the loop.
char** ptr=(char**)arr[0];
```

`arr`has the type pointer (decayed from an array) to pointer to pointer to char.
`ptr`has the type pointer to pointer to char.

As you can see `ptr` has one level of reference less than `arr`. `arr`holds all the pointers to your declared arrays of type pointer to char. (arrP1, arrP2, arrP3, arrP4).
By dereferencing `arr` you get the pointer to one of these arrays.(arrP1 in the first iteration)

Then you print where the pointer stored in ptr[0] points to and iterate to ptr[1], to print this. After the loop `arr`gets iterated and yields the pointer to `arrP2` and you start again with the `ptr`-loop.

You have to keep in mind that arrays and pointers are quite similar(but not exactly the same) in their usage and passing an array to function lets it decay to a pointer.

**Edit:** David's answer is great, I misread the focus of the 2nd question, so this answer is a bit offtopic. I will leave it here, because I think it still helps understanding what happens with all the pointer magic. For a relevant answer especially about const correctness David's answer is the one.

Comment: I think what you are getting at is the parameter is `const char** arr[]`, but then the declaration of `char** ptr=arr;` discards the `const` qualifier resulting in "fudging" with a cast `char** ptr=(char**)*arr;` to make the pointer types work? But given the levels of indirection, it appears separating what is in fact `const` qualified is lost in the shuffle in the original code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I seem to misread the question and lost that the focus was on the cast and not the assignment. The code also works without warnings without the cast, because if I am not mistaken the const only protects the strings here.

Comment: No, you didn't misread it, it was just unclear. But I think we are dealing with a language barrier issue -- so in those cases, if it can't be clearly overcome -- you just have to do your best to read between the lines to determine where he (or she) is stuck. It's made all the more fun when you are dealing with 3 levels of indirection (remember -- becoming a 3-star programmer -- isn't a compliment `:)`